# Rest assured 5.3.1 Multi Part form how to not have Mediatype post pended charset

Tags: rest, testing, rest-assured

I am working on a project were we I need to upgrade to Rest-Assured 5.3.1. I am finding that in the new version with in the multi part form the MediaType ( "application/json") gets post-pended with a charset identifier ("charset=US-ASCII") so the media type on the server side shows up as "application/json;charset=US-ASCII". The problem with this is that we are using an older version of java that does not match the media type with the extra parameter and I want to avoid any undo code changes within the app to just satisfy a test.

So, the main question is how to configure Rest Assured 3.5.1 to set a multi part section to specifically just be "application/json" but nothing extra?

I have tried a number of approaches to avoid this that was documented in Rest-assured and one that was suggested by our Architect without success.

One approach I tried was to and an encoder configuration.

```
given()
        .config(RestAssuredConfig.config()
            .encoderConfig(encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
```

This did not work with the individual multi part sections the individual media type showed the same thing.

Another approach was to add

`.httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig().httpMultipartMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE))`

to the configuration this disabled the media type specification all together causing the media type on the server to show up as "text/plain" MediaType.

So, the main question is how to configure Rest Assured 3.5.1 to set a multi part section to specifically just be "application/json" but nothing extra?

Here would be an example of something that I am trying to create.

Request Header:

```
POST /your-endpoint HTTP/1.1
Host: yourdomain.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebkitFormBoundary7MA4W
```

Request Body:

```
------WebkitFormBoundary7MA4W
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"
Content-Type: application/json    <----- ;charset=US-ASCII would get 
                                         post pended here..   

{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}

------WebkitFormBoundary7MA4W
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(binary data of the image)

------WebkitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Comment: please add the request you want to build.